# Handling non-deleting entities in an N-Tier Architecture

Tags: repository-pattern, n-tier-architecture

What is the best practice approach to handling non-deleting entities in an N-Tier Architecture. The architecture in question has a service layer and a repository layer. The repository is the only layer that has direct access to the database (well, through an ORM). Currently, the repository layer deals mostly with CRUD operations. Should this layer handle the retrieval of entities based on a given status?

Let me explain the use of status in our system. We want to use status to delete entities. So instead of deleting a User entity, we would set its status do Deleted. Now, the User Repository exposes a Get method. Calling Get without any parameters should return all Users in the system, regardless of its Status, but if we wanted to only get Active Users, would it be best to deal with that in the Service layer, or the Repository layer. If we were to do it in the Service layer, we would need to come up with a filter on the Repository Get methods response. If we did it in the Repository layer, we would have Get take a Status enum, so you could call Get(Status.Active). What would be the best way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest limiting Get(id) to retrieving the details for a specific entity and then implement some type of Find/Search functionality that accepted a SearchCriteria object to define your search parameters (such as Status).  To answer your question about where to do the filter, I would suggest the database since it is optimized for query execution.